# Can you walk through rooms with aliens?

Tags: the-captain-is-dead

Being in a room with an alien prevents you from walking out, but can you walk through a room with an alien as a 2 room move originating from a room that didn't have an alien?

Answer (score 3):

No you can't as the allowed actions that you can do are not based just on your starting or ending location. As soon as you enter a room with a hostile alien you will be limited to either killing it or using the teleporter to leave that room.

If you look at the action card it only lists kill a hostile alien in your location as an action

[English Rules](https://s3.amazonaws.com/download.thegamecrafter.com/1492261590/English%20Rules.pdf)

> Move up top 2 spaces (can do when injured)
>
> Kill a hostile alien in your location (can do when injured, must do when a hostile alien is present)
>
> Cary another player 1 space
>
> Give a skill or tool to another player in your location
>
> Take a skill or tool from another player in your loctation

If you look at the teleporter card it shows that it can be used remotly, while injured or while a hostile alien is present.

Comment: I feel this is the intent of the rules, but the rules do not explicitly confirm one way or another whether having a space with aliens in it as the first of two spaces of the move action causes the remainder of the move action to be forfeit. The argument I see against it is that you don't start your second action until the first action has been performed fully, and if you're intending to move two spaces (e.g. from one hallway to a different hallway) and the first space you move into has aliens in them, your move action hasn't been fully performed.